# Uso de Franquia de Dados para Ping Ininterrupto

Tags: redes, mobile, ping

Tenho um projeto de monitoria de rede onde vou fazer ping de vários hosts através de uma conexão 3g/4g para cada host.

Preciso decidir qual franquia vou contratar e uma vez que os planos atuais simplesmente cortam o tráfego após atingida a franquia (não há mais redução de velocidade), isso é de suma importância para que o projeto tenha sucesso. Não pode haver queda de conexão.

Fiz os cálculos considerando 64 bytes por segundo para cada host:

`86400 * 64 /1024 /1024 * 30 = 158,203 MB por mês para cada host.`

Esse cálculo está certo? Se não, como devo fazer?